# llenar lista dentro de retrofit Onresponse

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit

El proyecto que estoy realizando es prácticamente una aplicación en android que consumo una `ApiRestFull` prácticamente todo funciona bien traigo los elementos los seteo y el `response.body` si responde los elementos .

**Error :** 
Al momento de declarar una lista de objetos fuera como global y dentro del retrofit intentar pasar una lista a otra prácticamente me lo deja a null; lo veo con el debug y claro que trae elementos.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Receta> receta = new ArrayList<Receta>();
    ListView listView;
    List<String> lsRecetaNombre = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        RecetaServicio servicio = retrofit.create(RecetaServicio.class);
        Call<List<Receta>> repos = servicio.listRepos("listar");

        repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Receta>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Receta>> call, Response<List<Receta>> response) {
                receta.addAll(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Receta>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error al procesar la soliitud", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        lsRecetaNombre = listaDeNombres();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lsRecetaNombre);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    public List<String> listaDeNombres() {
        List<String> lsRecetaNombre = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!receta.isEmpty()) {
            for (Receta r : receta) {
                lsRecetaNombre.add(r.getNombre());
            }
        }

        return lsRecetaNombre;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te da algún error o es que mete un null a la lista? ¿Esta es la linea que te falla receta.addAll(response.body());?

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo desgraciadamente fue " que retrofit es asyncrono " asi que cuando yo  corro la app no carga todabia la lista para llenar el arrayadapter